# VBScript: Read a text file into another one without skipping last line

Tags: vba, csv, vbscript

I'm currently writing a VBscript to copy data from one text file into another with the goal of skipping the first row.
I got a version working with some code I found online, but it does not only skip the first line (this part is working) but it also skips the last line for some reason. I do not want to skip the last line, but I can't figure out what part of the code actually skips my last line.
Need: Copy all lines(rows) except first
Current code: Copy all lines(rows) except first and last

The text files are both CSV files.
Anyone an idea how to achieve what I need, or what part of my code actually lets the last line skip?
Thanks in advance.

This is the code:

```
Sub ChangeCSV(strPath,strCPath)
    Dim objFileSys
    Dim objInText,objOutText
    Dim strData1,strData2
    Dim wFlg
    
    
    wFlg = False

    Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set objInText = objFileSys.OpenTextFile(strPath, 1)
    
    
    Set objOutText = objFileSys.OpenTextFile(strCPath, 2, True)
        

    If objInText.AtEndOfLine = False Then objInText.ReadLine
    
    
    Do Until objInText.AtEndOfLine  = True
        strData1 = objInText.ReadLine
        If wFlg Then
            objOutText.WriteLine strData2
        Else
            wFlg = True
        End If
        strData2 = strData1
    Loop

    
    objInText.Close
    objOutText.Close
    Set objInText = Nothing
    Set objOutText = Nothing
    Set objFileSys = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [AtEndOfStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ffk3x3bw(v=vs.84)) property instead of `AtEndOfLine`. Here's code that should do what you are expecting:

```
Dim objFileSys
Dim objInText, objOutText
Dim strLine

Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInText = objFileSys.OpenTextFile(strPath, 1)
Set objOutText = objFileSys.OpenTextFile(strCPath, 2, True)

' Read first line
If Not objInText.AtEndOfStream Then objInText.ReadLine

' Read remaining lines
Do While Not objInText.AtEndOfStream
    
    ' Get line from source file
    strLine = objInText.ReadLine
    
    ' Write line to destination file
    If objInText.AtEndOfStream Then
        objOutText.Write strLine
    Else
        ' Create a new line after writing the line
        objOutText.WriteLine strLine
    End If
    
Loop

objInText.Close
objOutText.Close

Set objInText = Nothing
Set objOutText = Nothing
Set objFileSys = Nothing
```

On the last line, it uses the [Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/6ee7s9w2(v=vs.84)) method to avoid creating an extra blank line at the end of the destination file.